# Signal lost while opening named pipe in blocking mode

Tags: c++, signals, blocking, signal-handling

**Background:**
I made a program,in which a "parent" creates 2 child processes (a sender and a receiver). I have implemented the children in such way that when one child fails, it sends a signal (SIGUSR2) to the parent. When the parent receives the signal, finds the other process (e.g. if a "receiver" sent the signal, then the parent finds the corresponding "sender" process) and sends a SIGINT signal to it. After that, the parent creates 2 new children. Inside the child's signal handler for SIGINT I do some cleaning (close a named pipe, deallocate heap memory and exit normally). I made the "receiver" child to always send a SIGUSR2 to the parent -and then exit-, so the parent will have to find the "sender" child, send a signal to it and create new children again and again.

**The problem:**
The problem is that only the first "sender" child receives the signal and the other ones (the new "sender" children) are stuck on opening a named pipe in non-blocking mode and never exit.

So I open the named pipe in blocking mode and the "sender" is stuck there. According to the manual of [open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), when a signal is received while waiting to complete an open, the function returns -1 and errno is set to EINTR.  **But it looks like the open system call never fails and the signal is never received**.

So in the **parent** signal handler of SIGUSR2 I send a signal as following to the "sender" process that corresponds to the "receiver" that sent the signal:

```
int stat;
cout << "Going to kill " << pidINFO2->myPID << endl;
int ret = kill(pidINFO2->myPID,SIGINT);
if (ret==0) cout << "SIGNAL WAS SENT SUCCESSFULLY" <<endl;

waitpid(pidINFO2->myPID,&stat,0);
cout << "AFTER WAIT" << endl;
```

And this is the whole **sender child's** code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;

#include "interface.h"

char* input_dirName, *common_dirName, *myID, *syncID, *buflen;

void SIGINT_handler(int signo)
{
    cout << "INTO SENDER " << getpid() << " SIGNAL HANDLER" << endl;
    /* Remove the pipe we created */
        /* Make the name+path of the named pipe */
        char fifoNamePath[4096];
        strcpy(fifoNamePath,common_dirName);
        strcat(fifoNamePath,"/");
        strcat(fifoNamePath,myID);
        strcat(fifoNamePath,"_to_");
        strcat(fifoNamePath,syncID);
        strcat(fifoNamePath,".fifo");
        /* ------------------------------------ */
        unlink(fifoNamePath);
    /* -------------------------- */
    delete[] input_dirName;
    delete[] myID;
    delete[] syncID;
    delete[] common_dirName;
    delete[] buflen;

    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     cout << "INTO SENDER CHILD -> " << getpid() << endl;

     struct sigaction term;
     term.sa_handler = SIGINT_handler;
     term.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
     sigfillset(&term.sa_mask);
     if (sigaction(SIGINT, &term, NULL) == -1) {
             perror("sigaction");
             return EXIT_FAILURE;
     }

    common_dirName = new char[strlen(argv[1])+1];
    strcpy(common_dirName,argv[1]);
    input_dirName = new char[strlen(argv[2])+1];
    strcpy(input_dirName,argv[2]);
    myID = new char[strlen(argv[3])+1];
    strcpy(myID,argv[3]);
    syncID = new char[strlen(argv[4])+1];
    strcpy(syncID,argv[4]);
    buflen = new char[strlen(argv[5])+1];
    strcpy(buflen,argv[5]);


    /* Create and/or open the named pipes (FIFO) */
        /* Make the name+path of the named pipe */
        char fifoNamePath[4096];
        strcpy(fifoNamePath,common_dirName);
        strcat(fifoNamePath,"/");
        strcat(fifoNamePath,myID);
        strcat(fifoNamePath,"_to_");
        strcat(fifoNamePath,syncID);
        strcat(fifoNamePath,".fifo");
        /* ------------------------------------ */
        if (mkfifo(fifoNamePath,0777)!=0) //try to make the FIFO
        {
            if (errno != EEXIST) //if we get an error and that error is different than EEXIST, then we send a signal to the parent to try again with a new child
            {
                perror("Error: ");
                delete[] input_dirName;
                delete[] myID;
                delete[] syncID;
                delete[] common_dirName;
                delete[] buflen;
                kill(getppid(),SIGUSR2);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        //if we don't get an error or if the error is EEXIST (which means that the fifo is already made by the other process) we open it

        cout << "before open in " << getpid() << endl;
        int fd;
        if ( (fd = open(fifoNamePath, O_WRONLY)) == -1) //we try to open the fifo "read-only" in BLOCKING mode
        {
            perror("Error: ");
            delete[] input_dirName;
            delete[] myID;
            delete[] syncID;
            delete[] common_dirName;
            kill(getppid(),SIGUSR2);
            unlink(fifoNamePath);
            exit(0);
        }
        cout << "Sender opened -> " << fifoNamePath << " on " << fd << endl;
        char buffer[50] = "SOMETHING";
        int rsize;
        if ( ( rsize = write(fd,&buffer,strlen(buffer)+1) )==-1)
        {
            perror("Error: ");
            exit(5);
        }
        close(fd);
    /* --------------------------- */

    cout << "send completed for " << syncID << endl;
    delete[] input_dirName;
    delete[] myID;
    delete[] syncID;
    delete[] common_dirName;
    delete[] buflen;
    kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);
    exit(0);
}
```

So I was expecting for all the "sender" children to receive the SIGINT signal from the parent but it appears that only the first "sender" created receives the signal and the others don't, although the parent shows that the signal was sent successfully

**The actual output I get is:** (They share the same terminal. Wherever it says INTO *** CHILD it means the parent created 2 new processes)

```
[child]INTO SENDER CHILD -> 23410
[child]INTO RECEIVER CHILD -> 23409
[child]before open in 23410
[parent]The process -> 23409 terminated with an error!
[parent]Going to kill 23410
[parent]SIGNAL WAS SENT SUCCESSFULLY
[child]INTO SENDER 23410 SIGNAL HANDLER
[parent]AFTER WAIT
[child]INTO RECEIVER CHILD -> 23413
[child]INTO SENDER CHILD -> 23414
[child]before open in 23414
[parent]The process -> 23413 terminated with an error!
[parent]Going to kill 23414
[parent]SIGNAL WAS SENT SUCCESSFULLY
```

And the terminal is stuck there. The **parent is blocked on waitpid** and the **child is blocked on open** (I guess, since it printed "before open in 23414" but not the message after the open system call).
So why didn't the second "sender" that was created receive the SIGINT signal by the parent, since the parent said that it was sent (SIGNAL WAS SENT SUCCESSFULLY).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I only glanced at your code, but you should look up what `SA_RESTART` does.

Comment: Also for the love of god use `std::string` instead of mucking with allocating memory for C style strings yourself. At the very least use `std::unique_ptr` so you don't have all those `delete`'s scattered all over the place...

Comment: This is for an assignment and I am not allowed to use std::string. About SA_RESTART, I don't think this is the case cause it means that return from that handler will resume the "open" primitive but I exit(0) from the handler anyway. The thing is, the handler is never called and I think it should be called either if SA_RESTART is used or not.